# json error loading data

Tags: asp.net, json, fusioncharts

I'm using fusioncharts in my asp.net application. Using xml as the data source the application works fine, but with JSON it's not working and that's after I set the data format of the FusionChart class to "json", like this:

```
(FusionCharts.SetDataFormat("json"))
```

and pass the .json data file to the RenderChartHTML 
function:

```
Literal1.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML("FusionCharts/FCF_MSColumn3D.swf",
    "Data/Data3.json", "", "BPOR", "700", "500", false);
```

The JSON format is correct, because I have validated it on JSONLint.

Any help resolving this issue is appreciated.

1. The error message says: Error in loading data.
2. I am using FusionCharts Free
3. Here is the code:

   ```
   {
       "chart":{
           "caption":"Business Results 2005 v 2006",
           "xaxisname":"Month",
           "yaxisname":"Revenue",
           "showvalues":"0",
           "numberprefix":"$"
       },

       "categories":[{
           "category":[
           {  "label":"Jan"   },
           {  "label":"Feb"   },
           {  "label":"Mar"   },
           {  "label":"Apr"   },
           {  "label":"May"   },
           {  "label":"Jun"   },
           {  "label":"Jul"   },
           {  "label":"Aug"   },
           {  "label":"Sep"   },
           {  "label":"Oct"   },
           {  "label":"Nov"   },
           {  "label":"Dec"   }
           ]
       }
     ],

       "dataset":[{
           "seriesname":"2006",
           "data":[
           { "value":"27400"  },
           { "value":"29800"  },
           { "value":"25800"  },
           { "value":"26800"  },
           { "value":"29600"  },
           { "value":"32600"  },
           { "value":"31800"  },
           { "value":"36700"  },
           { "value":"29700"  },
           { "value":"31900"  },
           { "value":"34800"  },
           { "value":"24800"  }
           ]
       },

       {
       "seriesname":"2005",
       "data":[
           { "value":"10000"  },
           { "value":"11500"  },
           { "value":"12500"  },
           { "value":"15000"  },
           { "value":"11000"  },
           { "value":"9800"   },
           { "value":"11800"  },
           { "value":"19700"  },
           { "value":"21700"  },
           { "value":"21900"  },
           { "value":"22900"  },
           { "value":"20800"  }
       ]
       }
    ]
   }
   ```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Are you using FusionCharts Free or v3?

Comment: Can you paste the __json__ code here?

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I am using FusionCharts Free.

The error message says: Error in loading data

Comment: FusionCharts Free does not support JSON format. Try using the Evaluation version of FusionCharts XT which will support JSON/XML format.

Answer (score 2):

FusionCharts Free does not support JSON format. Try using the Evaluation version of FusionCharts XT which will support JSON/XML format.

Otherwise,there is a JSON to XML converter for FusionCharts

```
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/Tools/FCDataConverter/
```

If your data is static, it is recommended to convert the JSON to XML and use it. So as far as your JSON is concerned, use this XML code and try.

```
<chart caption="Business Results 2005 v 2006" xaxisname="Month" yaxisname="Revenue" showvalues="0" numberprefix="$" >
<categories>
    <category label="Jan" />
    <category label="Feb" />
    <category label="Mar" />
    <category label="Apr" />
    <category label="May" />
    <category label="Jun" />
    <category label="Jul" />
    <category label="Aug" />
    <category label="Sep" />
    <category label="Oct" />
    <category label="Nov" />
    <category label="Dec" />
</categories>
<dataset seriesname="2006">
    <set value="27400" />
    <set value="29800" />
    <set value="25800" />
    <set value="26800" />
    <set value="29600" />
    <set value="32600" />
    <set value="31800" />
    <set value="36700" />
    <set value="29700" />
    <set value="31900" />
    <set value="34800" />
    <set value="24800" />
</dataset>
<dataset seriesname="2005">
    <set value="10000" />
    <set value="11500" />
    <set value="12500" />
    <set value="15000" />
    <set value="11000" />
    <set value="9800" />
    <set value="11800" />
    <set value="19700" />
    <set value="21700" />
    <set value="21900" />
    <set value="22900" />
    <set value="20800" />
</dataset>
```